# CSS | Shopping cart with variable height inside fixed div

Tags: css, cart, css-position

http://tinyurl.com/cc4qkee

You can see a cart in the right top corner.If menu isn't fixed it works fine, but if it's fixed and you put a lot of products in the cart you cant scroll down to see the rest of the cart.

I don't know javascript well, but I used a javascript method in another project http://tinyurl.com/bljpxm4 and the cart still doesn't work properly.

Any ideas on how to get the cart working properly and have fixed menu ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change the style of your cart popup? Maybe just make it a summary of number of items, total, etc. You could also try removing the images, and that would give you a lot more space.

Another idea would be modify your mouseover and mouseout jquery functions to change the style of the `#top` element to remove the fixed position when you are showing the menu. You would also have to remove the 30px padding from `#header`. This might get a little tricky. You would probably have to use position: absolute, get the current scroll bar position, set `top` to that, and monitor the scroll bar position to move `#top` up in case someone scrolls up. On mouseout, you would set everything back to how it was.

A third idea would be to set the height of the cart drop down, and use overflow:auto to give you scroll bars in the cart area.

Comment: I'm doing the stuff for a client, so the changes of style depends on him, but of course he wouldn't want it unless necessary.

#1 doesn't sound good
#2 too complicated for me
#3 doesn't look good

I've got another idea to make menu fixed, but the cart static